# Qt designer plugin does not load in Eclipse CDT

Tags: qt4, eclipse-cdt, qwt

I have installed the Qwt widgets and they run fine in Qt Creator and QT 4 Designer; however when I run the QT Designer via Eclipse CDT they don't show up. Any ideas what is wrong?

I am on x32 Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) and running Eclipse CDT 3.4.2 (Ganymede).

Note the Qt add in otherwise is working fine and I can create and debug projects - but the additional widgets is the only thing not showing up.

I also have checked the paths and ensured everything is there as far as I can tell. But of course something is not right.

Here are the paths where I have checked this (NOTE: Eclipse is installed in /opt/eclipse)

```
/usr/share/qt4/plugins/
/usr/local/lib
/opt/eclipse/plugins/com.trolltech.qtcppdesignerplugins.linux.x86/dependentlibs
/opt/eclipse/plugins/com.trolltech.qtcppdesigner.linux.x86_1.6.0/lib
```

Thanks.

Comment: For the stand-alone designer, there is a dialog that tells you the plugins it attempted to load, and if there was an error.  Does the Eclipse version provide this?  If so, what does it say about the Qwt plugin?

Comment: Hi, yes I saw that - the standalone designer loads everything fine without any errors. I don't know if there is a similar thing available for the Eclipse version - I tried finding it but could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build Qwt using the same version (and configuration) of Qt that you built the Eclipse integration?

Comment: No, I did not build it myself - installed it via the Synaptic Package Manager. It has version 5.1.1-1 installed.

Comment: Ah. Then that is probably it. Qt is kind of picky when it comes to which plugins to load. See here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/plugins-howto.html